# How to get the child nodes from a parent node from a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, hierarchyid

Say I have the following hierarchical representation in my database:

```
A
|_B_C
|_D
```

then I want to get the child nodes from A (or B).
and vice versa, I want to get the parent from a given child node?
<>

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   Node HierarchyID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   NodeLevel AS Node.GetLevel(),
   ID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 )
```

inserting the root:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (Node, ID, Name)
   VALUES (HierarchyId::GetRoot(), 1, 'A')
```

child B

```
DECLARE @parent HierarchyId = HierarchyId::GetRoot()
INSERT INTO tbl (Node,ID,Name) VALUES (@parent.GetDescendant(NULL,NULL),2,'B')
```

Comment: Table definitions, example data and required results would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select @child = node from tbl where id = 2;
-- get immediate ancestor
select * from dbo.tbl where Node = @child.GetAncestor(1);

-- get immediate children
select
    *
from
    dbo.tbl
where
    Node.IsDescendantOf(@parent) = 1 and 
    Node.GetLevel() = @parent.GetLevel() + 1;
```